# How to prevent a user from stopping an Android service?

Tags: android, service

I created an Android app and need to make it difficult for users to stop the main service that the app spawns during its startup process.  This is for a rooted Jelly Bean 4.1.2 device.  Here are some steps I've taken so far:

- Installed as System App
- Uses the Device Admin APIs
- `android:allowClearUserData="false"` is included in the AndroidManifest.

The steps I've taken so far takes care of *most normal ways* a user would stop/disable an app/process; however, when you check the running apps list in Settings -> Application manager -> Running, users can still hit the 'Stop' button on the long-running service that was started by the app (see picture below):

[image: Service from Running Apps]

Is there any way to prevent users from stopping the service here?  Or what's the best way to restart a service when a user hits this stop button?  I tried putting some code in the service's onDisable() function, but that function does not seem to be called in this case.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: As a user, I'd find that annoying. Besides, there's always the option to uninstall the app and stop it for good if necessary.

Comment: @Tom: Agree with you; however, this app is not like other apps.  This is a security app for an enterprise, so its expected to be continuously running.

Comment: Also, a minor point, but if an app is a system app, it makes it so that a user has to root the device to uninstall the app.

Comment: It's AFAIK intentionally not possible. You can even stop some rather important system services that way. Services are however restarted automatically if you started them [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

Comment: Starting services as 'sticky' only restarts them if the OS kills them (not users).  But good to know that other major system services can also be stopped this way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to prevent users from stopping the service here?

Having your app be a device administrator probably blocks this. It definitely blocks the "Force Stop" option.

> I tried putting some code in the service's onDisable() function, but that function does not seem to be called in this case.

Since there is no `onDisable()` on a `Service`, this is not surprising.

> This is a security app for an enterprise, so its expected to be continuously running.

There is nothing intrinsic to "a security app for an enterprise" that would require it "to be continuously running".

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare.  I meant onDestroy(), not onDisable().  You're right about the "Force Stop" option being grayed out with the app being a device admin, but this particular option is still available to the user (even with device admin).

Comment: @user1798667: In that case, I doubt that there is any way to block it.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I won't go crazy trying to find a way when there probably is no method to gray it out in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare i agree with your answer but there is an app on play store called "AppLock" that prevent service from stop by user in settings.it open password screen when user click on stop button. how they do it then?

Answer (score 1):

As explained above does not have this option unless it is executed as root, but you can create an AlarmManager when starting your service that runs from time to time, the system will run if the service is not running, it will be created again.